# Python classifier evaluation plots

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn

For R, I just found a great package to quickly generate some classifier evaluation plots https://github.com/ambiata/classifierplots/blob/master/README.md

Is there something like this for python / sklearn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give [scikit-plot](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot) or [yellowbrick](https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick) a go.

In addition the developers of scikit-learn plan to integrate some basic plotting techniques [[1]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7116)[[2]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8501).

Comment: sklearn-evaluation is another great option: https://github.com/ploomber/sklearn-evaluation